# Oracle SQL: How to display a HH24:MI:SS as "Hours: #, Minutes #, Seconds #"?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time

Title says it all, I want

```
19:33:25
```

to display as

```
Hours: 19, Minutes: 33, Seconds: 25
```

This is the query that I used to get 19:33:25, basically a date converted to string.

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(24 * 60 * 60 * (a.dateEnd - SYSDATE),'sssss'),'hh24:mi:ss')
```

Is something like this possible?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: What is the type of the starting data? is it a variable, a column, the result of some manipulation? What have you tried so far?

Comment: TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(24 * 60 * 60 * (a.dateEnd - SYSDATE),'sssss'),'hh24:mi:ss') ... So basically a date converted to string.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `EXTRACT(... from DATE)` function, but since you need a fixed string output, you can do the same using `TO_CHAR`. All fixed parts in the string format can be enclosed in double quotes, which gives us something like -

```
select TO_CHAR(sysdate, '"Hours: "hh", Minutes: "mi" Seconds: "ss') from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can EXTRACT single fields:

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (a.dateEnd - SYSDATE)) AS HOUR,
    EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (a.dateEnd - SYSDATE)) AS MINUTE,
    EXTRACT(SECOND FROM (a.dateEnd - SYSDATE)) AS SECOND
FROM a
WHERE ...
```

if you want it in a single column with the text, you can use CONCAT:

```
SELECT CONCAT('Hours: ' || EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (a.dateEnd - SYSDATE)) ||
              ' Minutes: ' EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (a.dateEnd - SYSDATE)) ||
              ' Seconds: ' EXTRACT(SECOND FROM (a.dateEnd - SYSDATE))
             ) AS time_string
FROM a
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have to start from a string value, you can try with some regular expressions:

```
with test(txt) as ( select '19:33:25' from dual)
select regexp_replace(txt, '([0-9]{2,2}):([0-9]{2,2}):([0-9]{2,2})', 'Hours:\1, Minutes: \2, Seconds: \3')
from test
```

This matches the numbers in the starting string and uses them to build a new string containing some fixed text ('Hours:', ...) and the matched strings

Comment: Thanks, however I've been trying to get it work with my query but I'm running into errors: http://pastebin.com/zbtpWX6X

Comment: The problem seems to be in your starting query, not in the regexp part

Comment: This is my starter query and it works fine, https://i.gyazo.com/9f093d3adf89822e4a06bd226a8dc0ee.png

Comment: The error is about date conversion format, you should better check that part